# R change column class by variable

Tags: r, data.table

In R I have a data.table `df` with an integer column `X`. I want to convert this column from integer to a character.

This is really easy with `df[, X:=as.character(X)]`.

Now for the question, I have the name of the column (`X`) stored in a variable like this:

`col_name <- 'X'`.

How do I access the column (and convert it to a character column) while only knowing the variable.

I tried numerious things all yielding in nothing useful or a column of NA's. Which syntax will get me the result I want?

Comment: Please make your question reproducible by sharing example data.

Comment: try `as.character(df[col_name])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
library(data.table)
DT <- as.data.table(iris)
col_name <- "Petal.Length"
```

Use `(` to evaluate the LHS of `:=` and use list subsetting to select the column:

```
DT[, (col_name) := as.character(DT[[col_name]])]
class(DT[[col_name]])
#[1] "character"
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks :). Didn't know that syntax. Normally I'm using python + pandas but for a customer I needed to use R.

Answer (score 3):

We can specify it in `.SDcols` and assign the columns to `character`

```
df[, (col_name) := as.character(.SD[[1L]]), .SDcols = col_name]
```

If there are more than one column, use `lapply`

```
df[, (col_names) := lapply(.SD, as.character), .SDcols = col_names]
```

#### data

```
df <- data.table(X = as.integer(1:5), Y = LETTERS[1:5])
col_name <- "X"
```

Comment: I prefer the other answer since the code is cleaner, even though this is more extensible (since using `lapply`) but in my case I only need one column :).